# Jacoco:1 of 2 branches missed

Tags: junit, jacoco

In my junit test, I have a simple validation as:

```
Assert.assertTrue("Wrong x", myObt.getDx() == 2000);
```

I am using Jacoco for code coverage.

I get message as: 1 of 2 branches missed.

Why do I get this message? I understand compiler adds more conditional logic, but it seems to be wrong here. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Validating using .equals instead of '==' worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should not run test coverage on your test classes. I should only inspect the production classes.